# Reading input from file with Chinese Characters that got mangled

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm getting stuck trying to convert an input string in char* to Chinese character encoding. An application accepts a Chinese string input ex: "啊说到" and when it is written into a file it turns into this "°¡Ëµµ½". I'm able to take this input and feed it to _mbstowcs_s_l() but the solution needs to be locale independent, so I'm forced to use either mbstowcs() or WideCharToMultiByte() but it looks like both would work for me if the input did already went through MBCS to UTF-8, which in our case isnt.

The project is using Multibyte Character Set, and I'm struggling to understand what is going on. One other thing is the input is coming from a different application and stores it into file.

The application that accepted the Chinese input is an MFC set to Multibyte Char Set and the os was set to regional Chinese Simplified, UI accepts the input and is placed on a CString, that is coped to a char*. This is that part where I don't know whats going on in the encoding, this application stores it into a file, then we read it using the other application, the string is read unto char*, thats when the characters seems to take the "°¡Ëµµ½".

Question is, how can I turn this encoded char"°¡Ëµµ½" back to its Chinese encoding "啊说到", with out setting the locale in _mbstowcs_s_l()? The problem is, we could be reading strings from other regional settings and the application wouldn't just know what character map to use unless we tell it to.

Comment: You need to figure out what encoding the application used, and use that same encoding to decode the string. Furthermore, your question doesn't mention what encoding you used to get the string "°¡Ëµµ½".

Comment: The application that accepted the Chinese input is an MFC set to Multibyte Char Set and the os was set to regional Chinese Simplified, problem is when the file is sent to the application that needs to read in the stored string, it wouldn't really know what the regional setting was used, but they are both set to multibyte character set, the application that'll read it isn't MFC.

Comment: MFC isn't the issue. It's the encoding, which could be 936 or 54936 (both of which are commonly used for Simplified Chinese). Try those.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks, but does that mean, I really have to set the local for the character map?

Comment: Read the bytes and then convert to Unicode according to 936 or 54936.

Comment: It looks like it's 54936. The character U+554A "啊" [encodes as  B0 A1](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/data/trunk/charset/data/xml/gb-18030-2000.xml), and [in code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), B0 is "°" and A1 is "¡".